# hash_map on AIX?

Tags: stl, aix, hashmap

I am porting a program to AIX which takes use of hash_map in many places.

For linux and solaris hash_map is included in _gnu_cxx package and stlport.

However, I can't find hash_map on AIX platform. Anybody know?
Btw, I have to use IBM compiler /usr/vacpp/bin/xlC.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `<unordered_map>` on the AIX xlC compiler. That's because `<hash_map>` is a gcc extension.

You'll need to change your code to use the different name (or do some jiggery-pokery with a translation layer).